# Netty: How to determine if a file has been completely sent?

Tags: java, netty, file-transfer

I'm trying to send files (pdf/bpm/jpg/png) from a java server app to a java client app. 
The file is sent in chunks. But how do I know when the file has been completely sent?

My first thought was to use `channelReadComplete` to get notified if a file has been send completely. But since it is also fired while the file is still beeing send, it is useless. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

The client pipeline:

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast( "FileChunkHandler", new FileChunkHandler());
```

The server pipeline:

```
p.addLast( "Encoder", new ObjectEncoder());
p.addLast( "Decoder", new ObjectDecoder( Integer.MAX_VALUE, ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled( null ) ));
p.addLast( "chunkedWriteHandler", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
p.addLast( "FileSenderHandler", new FileSenderHandler());
```

The FileChunkHandler on the Client:

```
public class FileChunkHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ChunkedFile>{
    private ObjectOutputStream oout = null;

    @Override protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChunkedFile msg) throws Exception{
        System.out.println( "channelRead0");

        if ( oout == null){
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( "/Users/user/Documents/tmp/test/bla.txt" );
            oout = new ObjectOutputStream( out );
        }

        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf)msg;
        int numberOfReadableBytes = buf.readableBytes();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[numberOfReadableBytes];
        buf.readBytes( bytes );

        oout.write( bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }

    @Override public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{
        System.out.println( "channelReadComplete");
        ctx.fireChannelReadComplete();
    }
}
```

The FileSenderHandler on the Server:

public class FileSenderHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

```
@Override public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{

    File file = new File( "/Users/user/Documents/tmp/test/test.txt" );

    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    ChannelFuture sendFileFuture = null;

    if (ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class) == null) {
        sendFileFuture = ctx.write(new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, raf.length()), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
        ctx.flush();
    } else {
        sendFileFuture = ctx.writeAndFlush( file, ctx.newProgressivePromise());
    }

    sendFileFuture.addListener(new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total) {
            if (total < 0) { // total unknown
                System.err.println(future.channel() + " Transfer progress: " + progress);
            } else {
                System.err.println(future.channel() + " Transfer progress: " + progress + " / " + total);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) {
            System.err.println(future.channel() + " Transfer complete.");
        }
    });

    ctx.fireChannelRegistered();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem (but am not completely happy with it yet). Further feedback is welcome!

I'm creating a FileStatusHandler which receives a model containing file information like length and name. These information are passed as parameters to a FileDecoder, which is added to the pipeline.

```
public class FileStatusHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FileInformationModel>{

@Override protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FileInformationModel msg) throws Exception{
    String name = "out_" +msg.getName();
    long length = msg.getLength();

    FileDecoder fileDecoder = new FileDecoder( length, name);
    ctx.pipeline().addFirst( CommonClientDefines.Handler.FILE_DECODER, fileDecoder );

    ctx.writeAndFlush( CommonClientDefines.READY_FOR_CONTENT);
}
}
```

The FileDecoder itself takes care of receiving the file content and removes the handler if the file has been received.

```
public class FileDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf>{

private final String name;
private final long length;
private FileChannel fileChannel;
private long receivedLength = 0;

public FileDecoder(long length, String name) throws IOException{
    this.length = length;
    this.name = name;

    Path directoryPath = Paths.get( System.getProperty( "user.home" ), "Download", "tmp", "test");
    Path filePath = directoryPath.resolve( name);
    fileChannel = FileChannel.open( filePath, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE );
}

@Override protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception{
    receivedLength += msg.readableBytes();
    fileChannel.write( msg.nioBuffer());

    if( receivedLength >= length){
        fileChannel.close();
        ctx.pipeline().remove( CommonClientDefines.Handler.FILE_DECODER);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your client and server to comunicate via sockets. When your client sends a file to the server,than the server should send the "File recived message" to the client.

Google "Send socket message in Java ",there are a lot of examples.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since this approach would require lots of refactoring of our code, this is not an option...

Comment: He is using sockets.